# Connection between WireGuard peers

Tags: networking, vpn, lan, wireguard

I have ubuntu server with wireguard IP 10.10.0.1

and two win11 clients with wireguard 10.10.0.2 and 10.10.0.3 IPs

with current config server can ping clients and clients can ping server, but clients cannot ping each other

here are their configs

ububtu

```
[Interface]
Address = 10.10.0.1/24
ListenPort = 51820
PrivateKey = <ubuntuprivatekey>

[Peer]
PublicKey = <client1pubkey>
AllowedIPs = 10.10.0.2/32

[Peer]
PublicKey = <client2pubkey>
AllowedIPs = 10.10.0.3/32
```

client1

```
[Interface]
PrivateKey = <client1privatekey>
Address = 10.10.0.2/32

[Peer]
PublicKey = <ubuntupubkey>
AllowedIPs = 10.10.0.1/24
Endpoint = myubuntuserver.com:51820
PersistentKeepalive = 60
```

client2

```
[Interface]
PrivateKey = <client2privatekey>
Address = 10.10.0.3/32

[Peer]
PublicKey = <ubuntupubkey>
AllowedIPs = 10.10.0.1/24
Endpoint = myubuntuserver.com:51820
PersistentKeepalive = 60
```

what to change to allow win11 clients to ping each other

thank you